# Get the cart items of a given Shopify customer via the Shopify Api?

Tags: shopify

I understand that the [Shopify Rest Api](http://docs.shopify.com/api) does not have the capability to return shopping cart items. I also understand that the [Shopify Ajax Api](http://docs.shopify.com/support/your-website/themes/can-i-use-ajax-api) has the /cart.js endpoint which allows you to retrieve the current user shopping cart. It uses a session cookie to identify the current user. But this means that the Ajax Api /cart.js could be used only from the context of a Shopify front-end.

Still I can see various Shopify apps or services that seem to be able to get the shopping cart for a given customer outside the context of a Shopify front-end.
Does anyone know how I can call the Ajax Api /cart.js or any other endpoint in the Rest or Ajax api, and give it a user id perhaps or a shopping cart id and get the cart items for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid the only way you can access the cart items is via the Ajax API you mentioned. Perhaps this is what the other apps you've seen use. [Maybe something like this](http://code.tiffbits.com/shopify-displaying-cart-items-on-remote-website-with-ajax-json/)...

Here's a couple of related topics on the Shopify forums:

- [Add to cart by customer id](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/add-to-cart-by-customer-id-203195)
- [Customer information in external app](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/customer-information-in-external-app-159284)